# How to read html text with formatting using beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Open html file in a browser, copy the text and paste it on word document.
Whole of the text is pasted along with the associated formatting and spacing.

How to do the same in python.

soup.get_text() reads all the text but formatting goes for a toss.

I have tried to read whole html.
However with complex tables being present in the html,
Reading just the displayed text is challenging.

Answer (score 0):

soup.get_text() extract raw text from your file, without the html tags and css styles used for formatting (as `h1`, `p` , `strong`,...)

You'll have to explicitly extract the blocks you're insterested in.

For a soup like :

```
html = "<h1>Title</h1><p>Text</p>"
```

You can get title and paragraph with :

```
for tag in soup.find_all(['h1', 'p']):
  print tag
```

Outputs :

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Other text</p>
```